# Pass Vue js search filter functionality through single file components with EventBus

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, v-for, computed-properties

I have the following components:

`/components/SearchBlogs.vue` Search component to filter on `blog.title` and `blog.description`.

`/components/BlogList.vue` Here I list all the Blog items.

**SearchBlogs.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="search" @change="emitSearchValue" placeholder="search blog">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { EventBus } from '../event-bus.js'

export default {
  name: 'SearchBlogs',
  data: () => {
    return {
      search: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    emitSearchValue() {
      EventBus.$emit('search-value', 'this.search')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**BlogList.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
  <div v-for="blog in filteredBlogs" :key="blog">
    <BlogListItem :blog="blog" /> 
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import BlogListItem from './BlogListItem'
import { EventBus } from '../event-bus.js'

export default {
  name: 'BlogList',
  components: {
    BlogListItem,
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      blogs: [],
      searchvalue: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredBlogs() {
      return this.blogs.filter(blog =>
        blog.name.toLowerCase().includes(
          this.searchvalue.toLowerCase()
        )
      )
    }
  },
  created() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/blogs')
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      this.blogs = data;
    }),
    EventBus.$on('search-value', (search) => {
      this.searchvalue = value;
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

In another *page* component **Blogs** I register both components:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Blog</h1>
    <TheSidebar>
      <SearchBlogs />
    </TheSidebar>
    <BlogList/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Can anybody see what's missing here? I want, as soon as the user types something in the search input (from the `SearchBlogs.vue` component), it start filtering and updating the list.

Comment: Hey man, add codesandbox I will edit it for you with a solution.

Comment: @Adam Orlov Here is the link to the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-ishizaka-0ic43?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) Hope you can figure out, thanks a lot!

Comment: do you want to use EventBus? There is no need for it. It can be done with it, but there's no point.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my solution [condesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-gagarin-rkqhc?file=/src/components/List.vue)

Here is an explanation:
You don't need to use EventBus. You can communicate with Search Component by `v-model`, using prop `value` and emiting updated `value` from the Input.

Then your Main (List) Component is responsible for all the logic.

1. It keeps the state of a Search
2. It keeps the items and filtered Items

Thanks to that your Search Component is very clear and has no data, that means it has very little responsibility.

Please ask questions if I can add something to help you understand

**UPDATE**:

1. EventBus is a great addition in some cases. Your case is simple enough, there is no need to add it. Right now your architecture is "over engineered".
2. When you have added listener on EventBus, on `created:hook`you should always remove it while Component is being `destroyed`. Otherwise you can encounter a trouble with double calling function etc. This is very hard to debug, tryst me I'he been there
3. Going with my suggestion gives you comfort of "no-need-to-remember-about-this" because Vue is doing it for you.

Hope that help.

Comment: Ok thanks for your explanation! Is the same principle working for my checkboxes on [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62413901/vue-checkbox-filter-component-not-working/62418011?noredirect=1#comment110392124_62418011). If I get this working I have to combine Search and Checkbox component on the List component and they should work simultaneously.

Comment: and in general what should use or advice. With or without EventBus?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, very clear. Based on your example I try adding the checkboxes. Can you see why it's not working? Here is the link to the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-rain-zx0mc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). Thanks

Comment: @meez 1. your filter logic was incorrect. 2. Your `value:prop` was registered as a String. It has to be the Array. Here ⏩ https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-sun-efo5h?file=/src/components/List.vue

Comment: I have a question. To structure my layout and routes I have the following adjustment: In a route component `Blogs.vue` I register my components: `<Search v-model="search" />
      <Checkbox v-model="checked" /> <List />`. Then in the data object: `search: "",
      checked: [],
      experiences: [],` Should this work? Because it's not filtering?

Comment: I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62467862/filter-vue-list-based-on-select-option-value) about filtering the list based on a select option. Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: And can you explain clearly how the `get()` and `set()` method works here, so I can learn from it. And why you have to use it in this case. Many thanks.

Comment: do you know how to solve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62482212/how-make-json-data-available-for-my-vue-dynamic-routes/62483314#62483314) maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues but essentially the computed prop `filteredData` will look like:

```
computed: {
    filteredData() {
      return this.experiences.filter(
        el => el.category.indexOf(this.search) > -1
      );
    }
}
```

Also, used quotes around `'this.search'` when passing its value back which made it a string.

Fixed sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-lamarr-is8jz

Comment: could also use `el => el.category.startsWith(this.search)`

Comment: just to understand the concept. What's happening here `el => el`? When and how do you use that?

Comment: its a shortened arrow function, its equiv to `(el) => { return el.category.startsWith(this.search) }`

Comment: based on your example I try to add the Searchbox. ToLowerCase method is important. I also added a second EventBus for the search is that desirable? Here is a link to the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-smoke-i4s0h?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/components/List.vue:2080-2266)

Comment: imo using an event bus in the main app is bad practice (event busses exposed from global plugins is fine i.e this.$modal.open() etc), instead use vues `@eventName=""` on the component ad emit it with `this.$emit('eventName', this.theValue)`

Comment: do you maybe have an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62482212/how-make-json-data-available-for-my-vue-dynamic-routes/62483314#62483314?. How to provide my json data for dynamic route detail pages? I provided a sandbox as well.. Many thanks