# Register multiple Vue components in parent component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, slot

I have a global sidebar component **TheSidebar.vue:**

```
<template>
  <aside>
    <slot></slot>
  </aside>
</template>
```

In **Blogs.vue** (a page component) I try to register two components.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Experiences</h1>
    <TheSidebar>
      <SearchBlog />
      <CategoryCheckboxFilter />
    </TheSidebar>
    <ExperienceList />
  </div>
</template>
```

It seems like I cannot register two components in a slot?

Is this a good setup anyway and who do I have to achieve this?

**Update**
It's just working fine now and I can register more than one component in a `<slot />`. I think some webpack building issue before.

Comment: What error is popping up when you attempt this? (I have a hunch but want to see what you're getting before assuming)

Comment: @Lanny Bose thanks it's working now. Think something with webpack building.. I have another [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62365339/pass-vue-js-search-filter-functionality-through-single-file-components-with-even) maybe you have a clue?