# Vue Checkbox filter component not working

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, event-bus

In a single file component I made a checkbox array:

```
    <label 
      v-for="(category, index) in categories" 
      :key="index"
     >
      <input type="checkbox" :value="category.value"
      @change="emitSearchValue">
      <span class="ml-2 text-gray-700 capitalize">{{ category.value }}</span>
    </label>
```

With EventBus I transfer the data to the List component:

```
methods: {
    emitSearchValue() {
      EventBus.$emit('checked-value', 'this.checkedCategories')
    }
  }
```

In the List component I listen for the EventBus:

```
created() {
 EventBus.$on('checked-value', (checkedCategories) => {
  this.checkedvalue = checkedCategories;
 })
}
```

Then my computed property look like this:

```
computed: {
 filteredData() {

   return this.blogs.filter(blog =>
   // if there are no checkboxes checked. all values will pass otherwise the category must be included
    !this.checkedCategories.length || this.checkedCategories.includes(blog.category)
   )
  }
},
```

In the console I get:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
```

Here is a link to a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-smoke-i4s0h?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Whats wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps there is no `categories` property in your data section ? Or maybe you should remove the quotes around `this.checkedCategories` when you emit the event ? We can not say for sure without a working JSfiddle.

Comment: @IVO GELOV here is a link to a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-smoke-i4s0h?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). Hope you see what's wrong, thanks a lot!

Comment: Error in fiddle is not the same as in question, issue with question is `checkedvalue` is being set but you're using `checkedCategories`, typo? one in pen is your assigning a method called filteredData but have a model set in data called filteredData

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone I refactored my code (it was because I am also testing with a searchbox). Can you see why it's not filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the computed prop `filteredData` to:

```
computed: {
    filteredData() {
      if(!this.checkedvalue.length) return this.experiences

      return this.experiences.filter(experience =>
        this.checkedvalue.includes(experience.category)
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-gates-9l6ze?file=/src/components/List.vue), only temp

Comment: Ok thanks. I have to combine it later with a search filter, so I have to rewrite the computed prop. Maybe you can see why the search is not working from my single file component? Here is the link to [the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62365339/move-vue-js-search-functionality-to-separate-component-and-how-to-emit-the-event?noredirect=1#comment110342184_62365339).

Comment: thanks for the accept, I had added string search in initial edit using some with indexOf

Comment: no it wont suit, ill answer the other question, is low hanging ;p

Comment: do you know why I can't use `checkedCategories` as event listener? Because I use `this.checkedvalue = checkedCategories;` I don't understand