# Filter Vue list based on select option value

Tags: vuejs2, computed-properties, select-options, vue-filter

I try to filter my list with 2 select lists based on the selected value. It seems like my computed filter is not working?

You should be able to filter the list on 'Price from' and 'Price to'

**List.vue**
My computed filter property:

```
filteredData() {
  const LowerCaseSearch = this.search.toLowerCase();
  return this.products.filter(
    product =>
      (product.name.toLowerCase().includes(LowerCaseSearch) ||
        product.category.toLowerCase().includes(LowerCaseSearch)) &&
      (!this.checked.length || this.checked.includes(product.category)) &&
      (!this.selectedFrom.length || this.selectedFrom.includes(product.price)) &&
      (!this.selectedTo.length || this.selectedTo.includes(product.price))
  );
},
```

In my registered component I use `v-model` to bind to the computed property `selectedFrom`

```
<Price v-model="selectedFrom" />
```

How do I bind to the other property `selectedTo` in one v-model and what's wrong with my filter?

I also use a prefix 'From' and 'To' to put in front of the options.

```
data: () => {
    return {
      selectedFrom: '0,00',
      priceFrom: [
        { prefix: 'From', text: '0,00', value: '0,00' },
        { prefix: 'From', text: '200,00', value: '200,00' },
        { prefix: 'From', text: '400,00', value: '400,00' }
      ],
      selectedTo: 'No max',
      priceTo: [
        { prefix: 'To', text: '400,00', value: '400,00' },
        { prefix: 'To', text: '600,00', value: '600,00' },
        { prefix: 'To', text: '800,00', value: '800,00' },
        { text: 'No max', value: 'No max' }
      ]
    }
  },
```

Is there a more elegant and D.R.Y way to do this?

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-meninsky-gtcbd) what I have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind an object to your `v-model` on the `<price>` component.
This way you can pass multiple values to and from your component, without having to use multiple props.

I would also suggest you convert your `value` in your selects to numbers, so it's easier to use them to compare to your prices.

You've also defined data properties and computed properties in the sandbox (`<price>` component) with the same name, this is not possible. So you should remove the data properties and stick to the computed ones to handle your data.

Fork of your [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-pond-2i32d) with my suggested changes.

Comment: thanks. The `created()` hook I don't understand. Should that one not be in the parent `List` component? What is it's purpose exactly?

Comment: And can you explain clearly how the `get()` and `set()` method works here, so I can learn from it. Many thanks.

Comment: By default, computed properties are `getters`. However, you can expand it to also define a `setter` with the shown syntax. Having a `setter`, allows you to assign values to your computed property (`this.computedProp = "Some new value"`). So when you try to get the value from your property, the `getter` method is ran and the returned value is displayed. And when you assign a value the `setter` method is ran and receives the new value. You can then do what you want this value, in case emit it to the parent every time it changes.

Comment: Do you maybe have any clue on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62482212/how-make-json-data-available-for-my-vue-dynamic-routes?noredirect=1#comment110500123_62482212)?