# How make json data available for my Vue dynamic routes

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a `List` component where I fetch my date from `db/blogs.json`:

```
created() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/blogs')
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      this.blogs = data;
    })
  },
```

In my `BlogDetail.vue` I have:

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => {
    return {  
      blogId:this.$route.params.id
    }
  },
  computed: {
    blog() {
      return this.blogs.find(
        blog => blog.id === this.blogId
      )
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

But how do I get the `blogs` data in this component, which I fetched in the `List` component?

Because now in the `<template>` section of my `BlogDetail.vue` I cannot access e.g. {{ blog.name }}

**Update:**

I try passing `blogs` with props:

Now I am accepting a prop in `BlogDetails.vue`:

```
props: {
    blogs: {
      type: Array
    }
  },
```

But from where (which component), I have to registering the prop like `:blogs="blogs"`?

**Update 2**:

This is what I have so far, link to [the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-gareth-mneqt)

Comment: you can send blogs using props

Comment: @tuhin47 ok! But from where (from which component registration) do I send `:blogs` ?

Comment: @tuhin47 I provided a link to the sandbox.

Comment: sandbox seems to be working :/

Comment: @ Lawrence Cherone No it's not working. What I want is from my `/db/blogs.json` get e.g `blog.name' and `blog.description` available to use in my BlogDetail.vue component? I can't get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-jackson-qum01?file=/src/views/BlogDetails.vue) is the working sandbox.

Firstly you need to import JSON data from your JSON file correctly. As:

```
<script>
import ListItem from "./ListItem";
import Blogs from "../../public/db/blogs.json";

export default {
  name: "List",
  components: {
    ListItem
  },
  data() {
    return {
      blogs: Blogs.experiences
    };
  },
  created() {}
};
</script>
```

Have to send props in the router-link as :

```
<router-link 
  :to="{ name: 'BlogDetails', params: { id: blog.id,blog:blog }}">More information
</router-link>
```

Comment: I updated my answer editing your sandbox.please check

Comment: many thanks. So you can just pass the props through the `<router-link>`, as simple as that? And where does it gets it's $route.params.id from, [explained here](https://vueschool.io/lessons/vue-router-dynamic-routes)? How does it know which `<router-link>`belongs to which id? It's different setup than in the video isn't it?

Comment: Here they use vuex for state management. they save all data into store and using those data in any component. So they need only the  id and by this id, they can get the original content any time

Answer (score 0):

You can send props to the child component in the tag name, in your case:

```
  //LIST component(PARENT)
  <tamplate>
    <BlogDetail :blogs="blogs"></BlogDetail> //CHILD component
  </template>
```

Comment: `BlogDetail` is a dynamic route component. I don't place the tag name anywhere..?